# Ajax-loaded form always send first value entered even if reloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to admit that I don't really know how to explain this "problem" that I have nor was I able to find a good title for this thread. Anyway, I will try to be clear because I'm not sure if I could add a JSFiddle or code snippet.

Let's start with the project. I'm working on some kind of DVD Library to be used on a local network only. There's a page that allow a user to add new films to the database. To do this, I use the Allocine API (A French equivalent to IMDB) to gather films informations. The user can enter a film title (Or part of it) and perform a search. All the corresponding films from Allocine will then appear.
If the user click on one of them, a modal window opens embedding a form that will allow the user to add the needed informations before sending the form. The form is then sent using AJAX and the result appear in the same modal window.
The problem come when I want to add a second film. If I don't reload the page before trying to submit the form another time, the value from the first film will be sent instead of them from the second one and that is driving me crazy.

Here's the javascript code used to send the form.

```
$("body").on( "click", "#AddFilmButton", function() {       
    var formDatas = $('#FormAjoutFilm').serialize();

    $.ajax({
       url : 'Functions.php',
       type : 'POST',
       data : 'Action=AddFilm&' + formDatas, 
       cache: false,
       dataType : 'html',
       success : function(result, statut){
            $(result).modal();              
       },
    });     
});
```

You may notice that I'm watching a *button click event* instead of a *form submit event*. That's because when I used the form submit event, the page was refreshed all the time, no matter if I was using **preventDefault** or not.
I'm starting to wonder if the sent value are not reset exactly because I have used this workaround. Could it be just that ?

What other piece of code would be useful to help you understand my problem ?

EDIT : just like @intale suggested, I have multiple form in the DOM because of this modal system. I made some progress with it. First, I can now use a proper event handler and I'm watching the form submit event as preventDefault now works. 
In the success function, I have added this line : `$('#FormAjoutFilm').remove();`
It works almost as intended in that the datas are submitted only every other time. :p
Still, it's better than the previous behavior and I need to fix it now.
Thanks for anyone who contributed so far. If you know why I need to send the form two times to get it work, let me know. This is what I have now. :)

```
$("body").on( "submit", "#FormAjoutFilm", function(e) {     
    e.preventDefault();
    var formDatas = $('#FormAjoutFilm').serialize();

    alert(formDatas);

    $.ajax({
       url : 'Functions.php',
       type : 'POST',
       data : 'Action=AddFilm&' + formDatas, 
       cache: false,
       dataType : 'html',
       success : function(result, statut){
            $('#FormAjoutFilm').remove();
            $(result).modal();              
       },
    });     
});
```

Second Edit : It looks like it's finally solved after a cache clearing. Thanks for everyone who contributed. :)

Comment: 99% chance that you have duplicated ids in the DOM. I suppose you are not removing the first form when appending to the DOM the second one (by doing `$(result).modal(); `). So when you do `$('#FormAjoutFilm').serialize()` , the value is picked from the first form.

Comment: Is the `#FormAjoutFilm` form defined inside the modal?

Comment: Did you try adding `$('#FormAjoutFilm').reset();` in the `success` function ??

Comment: @SarathChandra : Thanks for the suggestion. I already tried it before and it keeps telling me that `TypeError: $(...).reset is not a function`. @Kenney : What do you mean ? @intale : Maybe you are right. When the form is submitted, it is "removed" because the modal window is replaced by another one but I'm not sure this means it is removed from the DOM. I tried to look at it but saw nothing with Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Try reseting the form after the data is sent:

```
success : function(result, statut){
    $('#FormAjoutFilm')[0].reset();
    $(result).modal();              
   }
```

This will prevent your serialize function from getting the first submit data

Comment: Tried it already after @SarathChandra suggested it and it keeps telling me that `TypeError: $(...).reset is not a function`

Comment: Try changing it to `$('#FormAjoutFilm')[0].reset();` .

Comment: TypeError: $(...).reset is not a function occurs only if you have an element id called 'reset'. I can't think of any other issue

Comment: This version do not throw an error anymore and it deletes some of the datas. In fact, I'm getting two value from the form. An hidden input and a text input. With your code, the text value is reseted but like @intale suggested, I probably have multiple instance of the form. I'm starting to wonder if this is a good idea to do it like that regarding my JS skill. I should try something simpler maybe.